# How to make a custom OpenBSD distribution?

Tags: openbsd

**Goal**

Create a custom distro that comes with a desktop environment and other desktop utilities, general applications, custom `~/.xsession`, etc.

Basically, a simple image for usage with OpenBSD beginners.

The GNU/Linux alternative would be something like [TurnKey](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/).

---

**Potential Solution**

The OpenBSD installer includes '[File Sets](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#FilesNeeded)'.

**Question**

Is it possible to edit these File Sets and add my own packages? What about custom settings like for the `~/.xsession`?

Comment: See "Customizing the Install Process" in the OpenBSD FAQ at https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#site

Comment: Take a look at [FuguIta](https://fuguita.org/) - OpenBSD Live System. [github](https://github.com/ykaw/FuguIta). Other OpenBSD live projects [mentioned](https://fuguita.org/?FuguIta/Links)

Answer (score 2):

The ordinary OpenBSD installation procedure allows for installing an additional  site-specific file set called `siteXX.tgz` (where `XX` is the current release number, e.g. `67` for release 6.7).

The OpenBSD FAQ [says this](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq4.html#site) about that:

> The OpenBSD install and upgrade scripts allow the selection of a user-created set called `siteXX.tgz`, where `XX` is the release version. Like the official file sets, this is a `tar(1)` archive rooted in `/` and untarred with the `-xzphf` options. It is installed last, so it can be used to complement and modify the files from a default install. Furthermore, it is possible to use hostname-dependent sets named `siteXX-$(hostname -s).tgz`. [...]

You also have the opportunity to provide a script for scripting certain things during the installation process:

> If the `siteXX.tgz` file set contains an executable file `/install.site`, the installer runs it with `chroot(8)` based at the freshly installed system's root. [...]
>
> Example usage:
>
> - Set the system time.
> - Do an immediate backup/archive of the new system before you expose it to the rest of the world.
> - Have a set of arbitrary commands be run after the first boot. This will happen if `install.site` is used to append any such commands to an `rc.firsttime(8)` file [...]

Such a script could, for example, call `pkg_add` to install various packages, possibly from a local server if you so wish.